# Create a NW.js without a window

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

Is it possible to create a NW.js app (node), that don't have a window entry point?

I want to use NW.js, because I want to create windows, but not at the entry point. The app should work in the background, and open a window, at specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set show:false in the manifest file, later on you can open new windows and close them.

As for window entry point you can always set a blank page or a single javascript file to be executed at start

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#main

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#show

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways to startup your app in NW.js.

You could use a javascript file and control when your page will show in it. Your package will be like this:

```
//package.json
{ "main": "src/index.js" }
```

Or you could set window to not show initially, and control the application flow on other file.

```
//package.json
{ 
"main": "src/index.html",
"window":{
"show":false
 },
"node_main":"index.js"
}
```

I use the first way.

See the NW.js doc for more information about package.json.

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/